# Find difference between tables where values differ

Tags: sqlite, select, left-join

When I search for how to compare two tables in SQLite, and see what's differ, I mostly find answers like this:

```
SELECT B.id FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id = A.id WHERE A.id IS NULL
```

and yes, it's correct if you want do find all the elements (or values for keys named 'id' in this case) in table B that is not in table A, i.e. all the new elements in B if B is a later version of A.

But what if I want to find all the id:s in B where the *value* for a certain key (or keys) deviate from the corresponding value in A? For example, if I have two tables, A and B with id:s and positions, and I want to get the result **id=3** in this case, because it is the element in B that has a value that differ. What would be the easiest way to do that?

```
Table A                      Table B

id | x_value | y_value       id | x_value | y_value
-----------------------      -----------------------
1  | 29.9563 | 12.6764       1  | 29.9563 | 12.6764
2  | 45.5843 | 7.6733        2  | 45.5843 | 7.6733 
3  | 28.2313 | 15.6579       3  | 39.2003 | 15.6579

Result:

id
--
3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a `inner join` with your condition in the `where` clause.

```
select a.id
from tableA a join tableB b on a.id = b.id
where ifnull(a.x_value, 0) <> ifnull(b.x_value, 0) 
      or ifnull(a.y_value, 0) <> ifnull(b.y_value, 0)
```

Comment: What with nullable values?

Comment: Don't you still need a left join? I thought OP also wants values absent from B entirely. The example isn't clear but it does also say "I want more than that..."

Comment: Are you asking about table aliases? That's the only difference I see.

Comment: Ok. You might try it with the outer join to see if it works for both cases. The only snag is if x and y are nullable in A but you can still just add `or b.id is null`.

Comment: @ shawnt00 Sqlite does't have `outer join`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INTERSECT`:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373509)**

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6ec5f/2/0)**

```
SELECT tA.id
FROM TableA tA
JOIN TableB tB
  ON tA.id = tB.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT tA.x_value, tA.y_value
                  INTERSECT 
                  SELECT tB.x_value, tB.y_value);
```

I like this solution, because it is easy to extend. Just add new column names. No need to handle `NULL` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with shawnt00 that you can read the question that the goal was to find all the id:s where values have changed between the two tables AND id:s of new instances inserted to the second table. Here is the select-statement to accomplish that, if anyone is interested:

```
select b.id 
from b left join a on b.id = a.id 
where ifnull(a.x_value, 0) <> ifnull(b.x_value, 0) 
   or ifnull(a.y_value, 0) <> ifnull(b.y_value, 0) 
   or a.id is null;
```